# Firefox installed by snap, cannot open local help files for some apps - any solution?

Tags: firefox, 22.04, snap

I have 2 laptops with Ubuntu 22.04 installed, both have Gimp and libreoffice. On neither of them can Firefox 104.0.2 (installed or update by snap) can the local help files for Gimp or LibreOffice be opened by Firefox.

On my desktop running Ubuntu 20.04.5 with Firefox 104.0 both Gimp and Libreoffice can open their local helpfiles. Firefox was installed by apt I think. I am glad that I didn't upgrade Ubuntu to 22.04 on my desktop !

Is there any solution to this problem, without uninstalling the snap version of FF, as the apt install version has nothing in the official repository now?

I am reluctant to move away from the official path?

Comment: Do you have firefox set as your default browser?

Comment: Snaps run confined, meaning they have limited access to your root file-system improving security.. thus files need to be in specific locations.. Any file in $HOME can be accessed; but anything in system directories are out of reach (including helpfiles).  This can be avoided via copying the file to a /tmp directory so `firefox` can read it.. but a bug exists in `snapd` (eg. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1951210) which is currently being worked on to resolve the issue (still in progress)..  Sorry I don't watch `gimp` so don't know if that's being worked on...

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is not quite true that everything outside home is unavailable, as some stuff under/usr/share can be opened (docs for example) but I thought it would be on the security issue lines as you said. I can't believe that there's not been more of a stink raised about this

Comment: Yes there are a number of `snap connect` directories that are available; `/media` & `/mnt` the obvious examples - but they are defined paths only limited by [snap confinement model](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement)